# Fatal error: Cannot declare class MYCLASS Woocommerce Settings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website, and when I go to the WordPress admin page and click on woocommerce-settings it shows this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class WC_Settings_General, because the
>        name is already in use in
>        /(hosting)/website/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/settings/class-wc-settings-general.php
>        on line 0 The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please
>        check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

The beginning of class-wc-settings-general.php looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * WooCommerce General Settings
 *
 * @package WooCommerce/Admin
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

if ( class_exists( 'WC_Settings_General', false ) ) {
    return new WC_Settings_General();
}

/**
 * WC_Admin_Settings_General.
 */
class WC_Settings_General extends WC_Settings_Page {

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->id    = 'general';
        $this->label = __( 'General', 'woocommerce' );

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Get settings array.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_settings() {
```

etc. The webpage url that is generating this error is: `https://www.(mywebsite).com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings`

I need to know how to resolve this issue and get to the woocommerce settings. I have other websites that have woocommerce and do not have this issue, and I do not know where the other place it is declared would be.

If you need to know the list of plugins, please, let me know.

Please do not flag as a duplicate post as this is a very specific issue regarding woocommerce and WordPress that the other posts I have looked at (around 8 others) do not fix. I have checked for `require` to change to `require_once`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same error, except it was pointing to line 0.  I switched theme to Storefront and deactivated all plugins except WooCommerce, which fixed the problem...  then switched the theme back and gradually added plugins back in to find out which was the problem.
Hopefully this can work for you as well - it was just a conflict with me on an old plugin I thankfully wasn't using any more anyway.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have found the plugin, which happens to be the Hide Price Until Login (Modified) plugin. Unfortunately this is an essential plugin for the site. I did manage to get around it by going to 

`/yourwebsite/wp-content/plugins/hide-price-until-login-modified/includes/hide-price-until-login-class.php`

and on line 512 there is a call that looks like this:

`add_filter( ‘woocommerce_get_settings_pages’, ‘hide_price_until_login_plugin_setting_class_initiate’ );`

Once I commented that line out, it stopped the problem.